# Adding 3rd party c++ library into objective C project

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I have 3rd party static library.. It contains only (.h and .hpp) header files.. They are in C++ language.. But my project was in objective C. Can i use these libraries in my project and is it possible to call the c++ functions in my objective c project.. ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. C++ is fully supported in Objective-C. Just rename the relevant Objective-C implementation files from `.m` to `.mm`, and they start to be compiled as C++ now, instead of “plain C mode.” These .mm files can directly call your C++ code.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. Should i change my appdelegate file extension and main.m file extension also??? I just planned to change all the implementation files extensions into .mm.. Am i right??

Comment: You have to only change the implementation files that call C++ code. The others can remain `.m`, but it also doesn’t do anything bad if you rename them to `.mm` as well. So, if your app delegate and main don’t call any C++, you can just leave them as `.m`.